# Why dynamically create marshaled C delegate with implementation as parameter in C# for Unity?

Tags: c#, c, unity-game-engine, marshalling

I am writing a C# project that wraps a C library. Each function in the C library takes a callback as a parameter, and every callback is defined in the C library. In the C# project, I marshal the callbacks and functions so they can be called in C#

e.g.

**C library**

```
typedef void (*FooCallback)(void* userData, int result);
void Foo(void* userData, FooCallback cb);
```

**C# project**

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate void FooCallback(IntPtr userData, int result);

[DllImport("c_api", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void Foo(IntPtr userData, FooCallback callback);

private void FooCallbackImpl(IntPtr userData, int result) {}
```

While trying to use this C# project in Unity, I've run into several different problems where the callbacks are corrupted, or garbage collected during runtime.

**C# project**

This, for example, seems to fail randomly

```
Foo(data, FooCallbackImpl); // [1]
```

Whereas this gets garbage collected

```
Foo(data, new FooCallback(FooCallbackImpl)); // [2]
```

The only thing that seems to consistently work is

```
FooCallback fc = new FooCallback(FooCallbackImpl); // [3]
Foo(data, fc);
```

I can understand why [2] would fail, the garbage collector doesn't think anyone is still using it, but why is [3] better than [1]? What actually happens behind the scenes when you wrap a local function in a new UnmanagedFunctionPointer?

Comment: Does C# turn the value 55 into a pointer to an int with value 55?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie sorry, that was stupid of me. I just wrote that as an example, it's not in the actual code. Changed to generic "data" variable

Comment: So `data` is a pointer to an int? Or does C# turn the variable `data` into a pointer (reference) because it is used where a pointer is required?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie data can be anything, but mostly I create it with var data = new IntPtr(integerValue); As far as I've seen, it hasn't been the source of any problems, and returns the correct integerValue data when the callback returns. According to documentation, C# is supposed to marshal it to a void pointer, but it's never dereferenced in C-code anyway right now